# How to parse a string from arguments Java?

Tags: java, string, parsing, arguments

I have been trying to parse a string from arguments, I have tried

```
String.parseString(args[0]);
```

what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: The arguments are already strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`args[0]` should already be a string if it's coming from command line.

If not, use `String.valueOf(args[0])`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Note that if you're trying to validate the arguments and actually get meaning out of them, you can try commons-cli instead of manually running through them.

Answer (score 2):

As the `args` argument in the `main` method is already a `String` array, you can just use `args[0]`.

There is no such method `String.parseString()` btw.